# automorphism of a commutative monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $M$ be a finitely generated, commutative monoid.

What are in general the relations between $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(M^{\rm gp})$?

When is it true that $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ determines $\mathrm{Aut}(M^{\rm gp})$?

Comment: What is $M^{gp}$?

Comment: Is $M^{gp}$ the adjoint of the forgetful function from the category of groups to the category of monoids? That is, is $M^{gp}$ the universal group with a corresponding (monoid) homomorphism: $M\to M^{gp}$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes it is.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "determines?"  Do you mean if $M$ and $N$ are monoids, and you know that $Aut(M)\cong Aut(N)\cong G$, under what conditions on $G$ can we prove that $Aut(M^{gp})\cong Aut(N^{gp})$?  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews every element of $M^{gp}$ induces an element of $Aut(M^{gp})$ by translation. This is a subgroup. Any $a\in Aut(M)$ induces an element of $Aut(M^{gp})$ simply by $a(-x)=-a(x)$. Is it true that $Aut(M^{gp})/M^{gp}$ is in bijective correspondence with $Aut(M)$?

Comment: Every automorphism of $M$ induces an automorphism of $M^\textrm{gp}$, because $(-)^\textrm{gp}$ is a functor. But I see no reason for the converse to be true.

Comment: @ullo  You need to be precise before people can answer your question.

Comment: @ullo: Your comment makes no sense to me: the only translation which is a monoid or a group homomorphism is the identity: every automorphism of a monoid/group must map the identity to the identity, so I don't see how you are claiming that $M^{\rm gp}$ maps to $\mathrm{Aut}(M^{\rm gp})$.

Comment: Is at least the functor $(-)^{gp}$ injective? meaning that $N-> M$ injective implies $N^{gp} -> M^{gp}$ injective

Comment: @ullo: use `\to` for right arrows, by the way.

Comment: @ullo That last question isn't even about the automorphism groups. As I've said, you really need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's much to say in general. For example, if every element of $M$ is idempotent ($m^2 = m$) then $M^{gp}$ is trivial. To generate examples of this you can take any finite [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) with join as the monoid operation.

Of course since $M^{gp}$ is a functor every automorphism $M \to M$ induces an automorphism $M^{gp} \to M^{gp}$. But my point is this need not be injective.